# timePicker with multiple buttons

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener, timepicker

I hope someone can help me. I lack in OOP knowledge and am a newbie in android.

I have 6 buttons. Each button will call the timePicker and display the time on the button.
How do i want to differentiate each buttons?

Thank you.....

Here's the code..:

```
public class TabTwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button btnBrfkst;
private Button btnMtea;
private Button btnLunch;
private Button btnAftea;
private Button btnDinner;
private Button btnSupper;

private Calendar mCalen;
private int hourOfDay;
private int minute;
private int ampm;
int timePickerInput ;

private static final int Time_PICKER_ID = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_two);

    btnBrfkst = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnMtea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnLunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnAftea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnDinner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btnSupper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    mCalen = Calendar.getInstance();
    hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

    btnBrfkst.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMtea.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLunch.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAftea.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDinner.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSupper.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
        case Time_PICKER_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerListener,
                    hourOfDay, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener TimePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            // while dialog box is closed, below method is called.
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

                switch (timePickerInput) {
                    case R.id.button1:

                mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                int hour12format = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                String ampmStr = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";

                // Set the Time String in Button
                btnBrfkst.setText(hour12format + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr);
                break;

                case R.id.button2:
                mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                 int hour12format2 = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                 hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                 minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                 ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                 String ampmStr2 = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
                 btnMtea.setText(hour12format2 + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr2);
                 break;

                case R.id.button3:
                mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                 int hour12format3 = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                  hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                 minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                  String ampmStr3 = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
                 btnLunch.setText(hour12format3 + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr3);
                break;

                    case R.id.button4:
                    mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    int hour12format4 = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                    String ampmStr4 = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
                    btnAftea.setText(hour12format4 + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr4);
                break;

                    case R.id.button5:
                        mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                        int hour12format5 = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                        hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                        String ampmStr5 = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
                        btnDinner.setText(hour12format5 + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr5);
                break;

                    case R.id.button6:
                        mCalen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        mCalen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                        int hour12format6 = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                        hourOfDay = mCalen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        minute = mCalen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        ampm = mCalen.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                        String ampmStr6 = (ampm == 0) ? "AM" : "PM";
                btnSupper.setText(hour12format6 + " : " + minute + " / " + ampmStr6);
                break;
                }

            }
        };

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(Time_PICKER_ID);
}
}
```

Comment: i already edited my questions..thanx

Comment: What happens now when you run this code? What's the issue?

Comment: the .setText on the button does not work..when we choose the date, i want it to display on the button

Comment: i want to ask, from the time that user choose, can we do some alert notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(Time_PICKER_ID);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    timePickerInput = v.getId();
    showDialog(Time_PICKER_ID);
}
```

You need to set the timerPickerInput to be the id of the button so you know which button to display the time in.

Comment: @niques you're welcome. Please accept it as the correct answer so I get some rep for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your activity or fragment should `implements View.OnClickListener`.
Then each button should register each button like so:

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one); 
Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);

buttonOne.setOnClickListener(this); 
buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then in your onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View temp)
{
    switch(temp.getId()) {
       case R.id.button_one:
            //do something
            break;
       case R.id.button_two:
            //do something
            break;

    }
}
```

An other option is to set the method to be called in the layout file for each button using `android:onClick="myMethodOne"`. This way you can call different methods if you want or even the same method and differentiate on ids like you do in the onClick methods.